# Joining table on value included in joint table as extra value

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, objection.js

I've faced a problem I cant neither solve nor find solution in documentation and issues.
In short description, I'm building an ecommerce solution, where I have following models: Product, Variant, Attribute, AttributeDictionary

Shortly, whenever user create an attribute of dictionary type, then it's answers are saved on AttributeDictionary model.
Each variant has many attributes.

Let's present db schema:

```
mysql> DESC variants;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| quantity | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESC variants_attributes;
+----------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| variants_id                | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| attributes_id              | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| attributes_dictionaries_id | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value                      | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESC attributes;
+------------+----------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                                         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned                             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(128)                                 | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field_type | enum('text','number','dictionary','boolean') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| unit       | varchar(10)                                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| required   | tinyint(1)                                   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+------------+----------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESC attributes_dictionaries;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| attributes_id | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value         | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and models:

**Variant model**

```
public static relationMappings = {
    attributes: {
      relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
      modelClass: 'Attribute',
      join: {
        from: 'variants.id',
        through: {
          from: 'variants_attributes.variants_id',
          to: 'variants_attributes.attributes_id',
          extra: {
            value: 'value',
            attributes_dictionaries_id: 'attributes_dictionaries_id',
          },
        },
        to: 'attributes.id',
      },
    },
  };
```

Product Model:

```
public static relationMappings = {
    attributes: {
      relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
      modelClass: 'Attribute',
      join: {
        from: 'products.id',
        through: {
          from: 'products_attributes.products_id',
          to: 'products_attributes.attributes_id',
          extra: {
            value: 'value',
            attributes_dictionaries_id: 'attributes_dictionaries_id',
          },
        },
        to: 'attributes.id',
      },
    },
    variants: {
      relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
      modelClass: 'Variant',
      join: {
        from: 'products.id',
        through: {
          from: 'products_variants.products_id',
          to: 'products_variants.variants_id',
        },
        extra: {
          value: 'value',
          attributes_dictionaries_id: 'attributes_dictionaries_id',
        },
        to: 'variants.id',
      },
    },
}
```

There are solutions like filter for relations, was wondering about kind of modify function, that would allow me to join attribute dictionary value.

The thing i would like to achieve is whenever i fetch variants relation, it'd resolve attributes_dictionaries_id as value if not null

The point is that in fields of type text, number etc. values are flat, but for dictionaries, those are predefined and stored in separate db table.

I have no idea how to approach this problem, since the choice is saved as an id in joint table. It could be saving as flat value, but it wouldn't respond to dictionary changes then.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this problem with this code in Variant model attribute relation mapping:

```
 modify: (qb) => {
    qb.select(
      `attributes.*`,
      'value',
      Attribute.relatedQuery('dictionary')
        .select('dictionary.value')
        .where('dictionary.id', '=', raw('attributes_dictionaries_id'))
        .as('resolvedValue')
    );
  },
```

The only thing that I wonder about now is if I can merge `resolvedValue` and `value` and display it conditionally, kind of (ternary notation)

`return attributes_dictionaries_id ? resolvedValue : value`